# R sorting string by index string

Tags: string, r, sorting, indexing

I would like to sort a matrix by string index

For example

matrix is 
myMat =

      [,1]           [,2]

[1,] apple         1

[2,] banana      3

[3,] pear           4

[4,] blackberry  5

Index string is 
myIdx =

[1,] banana
[2,] pear
[3,] apple
[4,] blackberry

Result have to be
myResult=

      [,1]           [,2]

[1,] banana      3

[2,] pear           4

[3,] apple         1

[4,] blackberry  5

How can I sort like this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` package you can do it very easily

```
myMat <- data.frame(fruit = c("apple", "banana", "pear", "blackberry"), num = c(1, 3, 4, 5))
myIdx <- c("banana", "pear", "apple", "blackberry")

require(data.table)
myMat <- data.table(myMat)
myMat
##         fruit num
## 1:      apple   1
## 2:     banana   3
## 3:       pear   4
## 4: blackberry   5

setkey(myMat, fruit)
myMat[J(myIdx)]

##         fruit num
## 1:     banana   3
## 2:       pear   4
## 3:      apple   1
## 4: blackberry   5
```

Comment: thanks. I tried to install data.table package. but cannot read the package. I did "install.packages("data.table")" then "require(data.table)". it shows "Loading required package: data.table
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘data.table’" message. Did I do wrong?